# How to remove space/shadow between items in a list

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this template consisting on a list of cards:

```
<div class="list">
<div class="card" ng-repeat="event in eventsSportsDay21">

    <div class="item item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-click="toggleEvent(event)">
        <!--ng-style="{'background-color': event.eventColor }">-->
        <img src={{event.eventIcon}}>
        <i class="icon" ng-class="isEventShown(event) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
        <h2><b>{{event.eventTitle}}</b></h2>
        <p><b>{{event.eventHour}}</b></p>
    </div>

    <div class="item item-body" ng-hide="!isEventShown(event)">
        <div>
            <!--<img src="/img/alfarero.jpg" width="30%" style="float: left; margin: 0 20px 20px 0;" ng-show="false">-->
            <p ng-bind-html="event.eventText | hrefToJS"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <!--<p style="clear: both">-->
            <br/>
            <div>
                <i class="icon ion-map balanced" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<p ng-bind-html="event.eventPlace | hrefToJS" style="display:inline"></p>

            </div>
             <!--</p>-->
             <!--<div>-->
                <div ng-show="event.eventPhone">
                    <i class="icon ion-information-circled balanced" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<p ng-bind-html="event.eventPhone | hrefToJS" style="display:inline"></p>
                </div>
             <!--</div>-->

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

It does its job but I want to tweak it a bit visually. First, I would like to remove shadows at the bottom of each card. Second, how do I eliminate space between cards?. Is there a way other than CSS?.

This is what I get:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: This can only be done with `CSS` the only reason you are getting the current results is because of `CSS`

Comment: Thanks, Gary. It is strange because in all ionic list examples this does not happen. So I have tried to remove the "card" class and it does work as expected now. The very first of the template would be wha I have posted below.

Comment: use css:  .card { box-shadow: 0 0px 1px; }

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is wanting to use cards when they are not needed. Changing to:

```
<div class="list">
<div ng-repeat="event in eventsSportsDay21">
```

gives the desired behaviour.